# Como fazer boxplots mensais, trimestrais, semestrais, anuais e a cada 10 anos para um período de 30 anos?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Preciso criar vários boxplots com intervalos diferentes de dados. Possuo um data-frame composto por precipitações da cidade de Alagoas e preciso comparar com outro data-frame com dados de precipitações da cidade de Viçosa. Pensei em fazer essa comparação utilizando boxplots para os seguintes casos:

1. Boxplots mensais para cada ano (1990-2019).

Conforme feito pelo colega “LuizZ” mas inserindo para cada ano os valores da segunda cidade. De forma a ficar para cada ano os boxplots da cidade de Alagoas em cima e embaixo da cidade de Viçosa.

2. Boxplots trimestrais para cada ano (1990-2019).

A representação gráfica seria no mesmo estilo que o colega “LuizZ” fez, mas inserindo para cada ano os valores da segunda cidade. De forma a ficar para cada ano os boxplots da cidade de Alagoas em cima e embaixo da cidade de Viçosa.

3. Boxplots semestrais para cada ano (1990-2019).

A representação gráfica seria no mesmo estilo que o colega “LuizZ” fez, mas inserindo para cada ano os valores da segunda cidade. De forma a ficar para cada ano os boxplots da cidade de Alagoas em cima e embaixo da cidade de Viçosa.

4. Boxplots anuais (1990-2019).

A representação gráfica seria no mesmo estilo que o colega “LuizZ” fez, mas inserindo para cada ano os valores da segunda cidade. De forma a ficar para cada ano os boxplots da cidade de Alagoas em cima e embaixo da cidade de Viçosa.

5. Boxplots a cada 10 anos (1990-2019).

A representação gráfica seria no mesmo estilo que o colega “LuizZ” fez, mas inserindo para década os valores da segunda cidade. De forma a ficar para cada década os boxplots da cidade de Alagoas em cima e embaixo da cidade de Viçosa.

---

A única forma que sei fazer o boxplot é selecionando toda a coluna que estão os dados de precipitação (10958 precipitações para os 10957 dias dos 30 anos (1990-2019)) e ainda fazer separadamente para cada cidade:

```
cidade1 <- read.csv("Alagoas.csv", header = T, skip = 0)
boxplot(cidade1$prec)
cidade2 <- read.csv("Vicosa.csv", header = T, skip = 0)
boxplot(cidade2$prec)
```

Mas gostaria de aprender uma forma de selecionar somente as datas do data-frame e construir os boxplots para cada cidade e dispor os gráficos das duas cidades de forma comparativa visualmente. Seria possível?

Obs.: Não consegui entender como utilizar o dput(dados) sugerido pelos colegas Rui Barradas e Carlos Eduardo Lagosta mesmo pesquisando como utilizá-lo. Peço desculpas por isso, mas iniciei há pouco a programar em R e tem sido um desafio para mim. Tentando responder minimente de forma descritiva o que entendi ser o dput(dados), o data-frame da cidade de Alagoas está em formato .csv e os valores de prec estão em milímetros, dispostos da seguinte forma:

```
Data        prec
01/01/1990  8,9
02/01/1990  32,7
03/01/1990  0,3
04/01/1990  3,9
05/01/1990  8,8
06/01/1990  29,2
07/01/1990  2,5
08/01/1990  0,6
09/01/1990  27,7
10/01/1990  11,2
11/01/1990  9,8
12/01/1990  0
13/01/1990  6,6
14/01/1990  0
15/01/1990  0
16/01/1990  0
17/01/1990  0
18/01/1990  0
19/01/1990  5,5
20/01/1990  0
21/01/1990  0
22/01/1990  0
23/01/1990  0
24/01/1990  6,2
25/01/1990  0
26/01/1990  0
27/01/1990  19,4
28/01/1990  15,1
29/01/1990  0,9
30/01/1990  16,4
31/01/1990  0
01/02/1990  0
02/02/1990  0
03/02/1990  0
04/02/1990  0
05/02/1990  0
06/02/1990  0
07/02/1990  0,1
08/02/1990  10,1
09/02/1990  0,1
10/02/1990  0,2
11/02/1990  1,3
12/02/1990  2,4
13/02/1990  2,6
14/02/1990  0
15/02/1990  0
16/02/1990  4,8
17/02/1990  0
18/02/1990  0,6
19/02/1990  7,1
20/02/1990  4,1
21/02/1990  0
22/02/1990  5
23/02/1990  0
24/02/1990  2,3
25/02/1990  6,3
26/02/1990  9,1
27/02/1990  25,7
28/02/1990  8,3
...
31/12/2019  0,5
```

Para a cidade de Viçosa a disposição é a mesma:

```
Data        prec 
01/01/1990  0
02/01/1990  14,2
03/01/1990  0
04/01/1990  1
05/01/1990  4,8
06/01/1990  0
07/01/1990  0,4
08/01/1990  0
09/01/1990  0
10/01/1990  0
11/01/1990  0
12/01/1990  0
13/01/1990  2,6
14/01/1990  0
15/01/1990  0
16/01/1990  0
17/01/1990  0
18/01/1990  0
19/01/1990  0
20/01/1990  0
21/01/1990  2,4
22/01/1990  1,8
23/01/1990  0
24/01/1990  0
25/01/1990  0
26/01/1990  0
27/01/1990  4
28/01/1990  0
29/01/1990  3,8
30/01/1990  11,8
31/01/1990  0
01/02/1990  0
02/02/1990  0
03/02/1990  0
04/02/1990  0
05/02/1990  0
06/02/1990  0
07/02/1990  0
08/02/1990  0
09/02/1990  90
10/02/1990  21,4
11/02/1990  0
12/02/1990  0
13/02/1990  0
14/02/1990  0
15/02/1990  0
16/02/1990  0
17/02/1990  0
18/02/1990  0
19/02/1990  0
20/02/1990  0
21/02/1990  0
22/02/1990  0
23/02/1990  0
24/02/1990  0
25/02/1990  0,2
26/02/1990  24
27/02/1990  9,6
28/02/1990  5,4
...
31/12/2019  1,2
```

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(dados)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(dados, 20))`? Nota: `dados` é o nome da base.

Comment: O que quer exatamente? Selecionar um mês específico para plotar? Comparar um mesmo mês para vários anos? Um gráfico com todos os meses e anos? Além de uma amostra dos seus dados usando `dput`, inclua um exemplo de qual resultado final deseja.

Comment: Bruna, parece-me que sua pergunta ficou muito complexa e pedindo muitas coisas. Sugiro que foque em apenas uma questão, procure ser mais objetiva veja esse link a respeito: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Sobre como utilizar o `dput()`: é muito simples, basta colocar o nome do seu dataframe dentro dos parênteses e rodar. Vai sair um resultado meio estranho, você cola esse resultado aqui no formato de código. Veja exemplos de como utilizar o dput() nesse link: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r

Comment: Seu dataframe possui mais de 10 mil linhas. Talvez uma opção seja selecionar dois anos apenas: `dput(head(cidade1, 730))` . Funciona mais ou menos assim: você pede uma coisa específica por pergunta. Se você quer muitas coisas. Pede primeiro o mais simples. Depois que tiver a resposta, você tenta reproduzi-la, compreendê-la, e fazer o mais complexo sozinha. Se não conseguir, pede ajuda de novo aqui em outra pergunta para fazer o mais complexo.

Comment: LuizZ obrigada pela orientação. Vi os tutoriais que me passou e irei reformular minha pergunta em breve!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como você não forneceu os dados completos, podemos criar algo semelhante a eles pelas características descreveu. Esse dataframe vai se chamar `df`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

temp_date <- seq(from=as.Date("1990-01-01"), to=as.Date("2019-12-31"), by="day")
data <- format(as.Date(temp_date), format = "%d/%m/%Y") 
set.seed(1)
prec <- rnorm(10957, mean=1.5, sd=0.3)
df <- data.frame(data, prec)
```

Se suas datas não estiverem no formato `Date`, então é útil convertê-las para esse formato, se já estiverem, você não precisa rodar a linha abaixo:

```
df$data <- lubridate::dmy(df$data)
```

Em seguida, vamos criar uma coluna com apenas os meses e outra com apenas os anos, para utilizá-las nos boxplots:

```
df$mes <- format(as.Date(df$data), "%m")
df$ano <- format(as.Date(df$data), "%Y")
```

Por fim, construímos os boxplots:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=mes, y=prec)) + 
    geom_boxplot() +
    facet_wrap(~ano)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bem, essa é uma visualização possível. O resultado ficou bem comprimido. Outra visualizações são possíveis. Você pode, por exemplo, atribuir uma cor diferente para cada mês do ano:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=mes, y=prec, fill=mes)) + 
    geom_boxplot() +
    facet_wrap(~ano)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Editado**:

Bem, você editou sua pergunta, solicitando a construção de novos boxplots para diversos períodos. Acima, eu já havia mostrado como criar variáveis separadas para os meses e os anos. Agora vou te mostrar como recodificar essas variáveis e fazer um gráfico combinando dois desses períodos. Basta você seguir esse modelo e ajustar para quaisquer outros períodos que você possa desejar.

**Recodificação das variáveis para criação dos períodos:**

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    trimestre = case_when(
      as.numeric(mes) <4 ~ "1",
      as.numeric(mes) <7 ~ "2",
      as.numeric(mes) <10 ~ "3",
      TRUE ~ "4"),
    semestre = case_when(
      as.numeric(mes) <7 ~ "1",
      TRUE ~ "2"),
    decada = case_when(
      as.numeric(ano) < 2000 ~ "1990 - 1999",
      as.numeric(ano) < 2010 ~ "2000 - 2009",
      TRUE ~ "2010 - 2019")) %>% 
   mutate(
      tri_ano = paste(trimestre, substr(ano, 4, 4), sep="/"),
      sem_ano = paste(semestre, substr(ano, 3, 4), sep="/"))
```

Repare no código acima que para construir a variável de `tri_ano` eu peguei apenas o último dígito do ano. Isso foi necessário para que os trimestres ficassem alinhados para as diversas décadas no gráfico abaixo. Na variável de `sem_ano`, peguei os dois últimos dígitos, para você notar a diferença do código. Você pode ajustar esses parâmetros de acordo com a sua necessidade.

**Boxplot por trimestre e década:**

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=tri_ano, y=prec, fill=trimestre)) + 
    geom_boxplot() +
    theme(
      legend.position = "none",
      plot.title = element_text(size=20, hjust = 0.5),
      axis.text.x = element_text(angle=-90)) +
    labs(title="Precipitação por trimestre e década em Alagoas",
        x ="trimestre/ano",
        y = "precipitação") +
    facet_wrap(~decada, nrow=3)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode observar acima que indiquei no título que esse gráfico é para a cidade de Alagoas. Ou seja, você usará os dados de Alagoas com esse título, repare no código acima, onde Alagoas está escrito. Para fazer o mesmo gráfico para Viçosa, basta você utilizar os dados de Viçosa e indicar no título a diferença. Depois você posiciona os gráficos onde quiser no seu trabalho.